# Why does my asynchronous function below get the error code 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'message' has already been declared"?

Tags: javascript, async-await

My asynch function is as follows

-----------------------------------------

```
    /* async/await */
    async function demoPromise() {
        try {
            let message = await myPromise;
            let message = await helloPromise();
            console.log(message);
    
        } catch ((error) => {
            console.log("Error:" + error.message);
        })
    }
    
    /* call the async function */
    
    (async () => {
        await myDate();
    })();
```

---

The myPromise code block is:

============================

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const condition = true;
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("Promise is resolved!"); // fulfilled
        }, 300);
    } else {
        reject('Promise is rejected!');
    }
});
```

---

And the `helloPromise() code block is:-

```
const helloPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const message = `Hi, How are you!`;

        resolve(message)
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the `let` from the second line.

Comment: When I remove `let` from the second line I get another error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

Comment: `let message = await myPromise` change this to `let message = await myPromise()` and also you are overwriting message so just remove second `let`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot declare 2 variables with the same name so either remove `let` from the 2nd message variable (this will override the promise result though) or give the 2nd message variable another name ex. `let anotherMessage = await helloPromise();`

Moreover, i think the 1st promise `myPromise` is missing a `()`. It should be `let message = await myPromise();`

Comment: But should'nt `myPromise` resolve before going to the next promise `helloPromise()`. Since they reslove sequentially why would it matter if  `let` is declared twice with `message`?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the Promise event but with the declaration of variables.

`let` declares a unique variable that can change its value. We cannot have 2 unique named variables on the same scope. Check [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for the `let` explanation

Comment: you are throwing away the result of the first call, is the point. if you don't need the result of the first call, don't store it in a variable. If you do need both values, use two different names.

Comment: Now I get an error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('` from the `catch` line in the code.

Comment: `const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const condition = true;
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("Promise is resolved!"); // fulfilled
        }, 300);
    } else {
        reject('Promise is rejected!');
    }
})
);`
You are missing a `)` before the end of code! `);`